# Query less-than / greather-than values in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

suppose an SQL table in Snowflake, where all columns are **int** type (example table is at the end of the post)

I need a SQL query that returns the result of sum of less-than input values.
For clarity, here is the query that works for filtering by **column x**:

```
select 
    max(cumsum.cumulative),
    xlimit.val
from (select 
        source.x,
        sum(source.y) over(order by source.x asc range between unbounded preceding and current row) as cumulative 
      from sampletable source) as cumsum
        join (select * from values (3), (5), (10)) as xlimit(val)
            on cumsum.x < xlimit.val
    group by xlimit.val;
```

The goal of the query above is:

"Return the **sum of column y** where **column x is less that 3, 5 and 10** accordingly"

The query input parameters are the 3, 5 and 10 that can vary

But if I extend this query to filter by **column z** greater that values, the query returns invalid values

```
select 
    max(cumsum.cumulative),
    xlimit.val,
    zlimit.val
from (select
        source.x,
        source.z,
        sum(source.y) over(order by source.x asc, source.z desc range between unbounded preceding and current row) as cumulative 
      from sampletable source) as cumsum
        join (select * from values (3), (5), (10)) as xlimit(val)
            on cumsum.x < xlimit.val
        join (select * from values (100), (200), (800)) as zlimit(val)
            on cumsum.z > zlimit.val
    group by xlimit.val, zlimit.val;
```

The goal of the query above is:

"Return the **sum of column y** where **column x is less that 3, 5 and 10** and **column z is greater that 100, 200, 800** accordingly"

The problem is that the expected result would be 210 if x < 3 and z > 100 but the query returns 300

Actual result:

| MAX(CUMSUM.CUMULATIVE) | x | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 3 | 100 |
| 700 | 5 | 100 |
| 1770 | 10 | 100 |
| 1770 | 10 | 500 |
| 1770 | 10 | 800 |

Expected result:

| MAX(CUMSUM.CUMULATIVE) | x | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 210 | 3 | 100 |
| 610 | 5 | 100 |
| 1680 | 10 | 100 |
| 960 | 10 | 500 |
| 100 | 10 | 800 |

Can anybody help me what did I wrong?

Example table:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00 | 000 |
| 0 | 10 | 000 |
| 0 | 20 | 100 |
| 0 | 30 | 100 |
| 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 1 | 20 | 100 |
| 1 | 30 | 200 |
| 1 | 40 | 200 |
| 2 | 20 | 200 |
| 2 | 30 | 200 |
| 2 | 40 | 300 |
| 2 | 50 | 300 |
| 3 | 30 | 300 |
| 3 | 40 | 300 |
| 3 | 50 | 400 |
| 3 | 60 | 400 |
| 4 | 40 | 400 |
| 4 | 50 | 400 |
| 4 | 60 | 500 |
| 4 | 70 | 500 |
| 5 | 50 | 500 |
| 5 | 60 | 500 |
| 5 | 70 | 600 |
| 5 | 80 | 600 |
| 6 | 60 | 600 |
| 6 | 70 | 600 |
| 6 | 80 | 700 |
| 6 | 90 | 800 |
| 7 | 70 | 700 |
| 7 | 80 | 700 |
| 7 | 90 | 800 |
| 7 | 00 | 800 |
| 8 | 80 | 800 |
| 8 | 90 | 800 |
| 8 | 00 | 900 |
| 8 | 10 | 900 |
| 9 | 90 | 900 |
| 9 | 00 | 900 |
| 9 | 10 | 000 |
| 9 | 20 | 000 |

Complete working example:

```
drop table if exists testtable;
create table testtable(
  x int,
  y int,
  z int
);

insert into testtable values
  (0, 00, 000),
  (0, 10, 000),
  (0, 20, 100),
  (0, 30, 100),
  (1, 10, 100),
  (1, 20, 100),
  (1, 30, 200),
  (1, 40, 200),
  (2, 20, 200),
  (2, 30, 200),
  (2, 40, 300),
  (2, 50, 300),
  (3, 30, 300),
  (3, 40, 300),
  (3, 50, 400),
  (3, 60, 400),
  (4, 40, 400),
  (4, 50, 400),
  (4, 60, 500),
  (4, 70, 500),
  (5, 50, 500),
  (5, 60, 500),
  (5, 70, 600),
  (5, 80, 600),
  (6, 60, 600),
  (6, 70, 600),
  (6, 80, 700),
  (6, 90, 800),
  (7, 70, 700),
  (7, 80, 700),
  (7, 90, 800),
  (7, 00, 800),
  (8, 80, 800),
  (8, 90, 800),
  (8, 00, 900),
  (8, 10, 900),
  (9, 90, 900),
  (9, 00, 900),
  (9, 10, 000),
  (9, 20, 000);

select 
    max(cumsum.cumulative),
    xmlimit.val xmlimit,
    zmlimit.val zmlimit
from (select source.x, source.z, sum(source.y) over(order by source.x asc, source.z desc range between unbounded preceding and current row) as cumulative from testtable source) as cumsum
        join (select * from values (3), (5), (10)) as xmlimit(val)
            on cumsum.x < xmlimit.val
        join (select * from values (100), (500), (800)) as zmlimit(val)
            on cumsum.z > zmlimit.val
    group by xmlimit.val, zmlimit.val;
```

Comment: Can you provide a table with the results you're expecting too? That'll help people understand your problem a bit more.

Comment: It’s not clear, to me, why you have 3 values in your comparison. Isn’t “ column x is less than 3, 5 and 10 ” the same as “ column x is less than 3 ”?

Comment: @NickW, 3 values (or n, depending on the user input) SHALL result 3 rows, each rows contains the sum of column y that satisfy the comparison criteria

Comment: It's possible you're trying to do this for the 3 pairs separately.  Instead of 2 joins, try something more like this: ```join (select * from values (3, 100), (5, 200), (10, 800)) as xzlimit(xval, zval)``` with the appropriate ```ON``` clause.

Comment: If not, can you post a runnable complete test case which produces the result you don't like?  CREATE TABLE ...;  INSERT INTO ...; etc.

Comment: Also, if you want a sum over just certain pairs, don't forget your PARTITION BY clause: ```PARTITION BY xlimit.val, zlimit.val```  or something similar, depending on which approach you use above.  This is your problem.  Your initial SUM is without regard to the criteria.

Comment: @JonArmstrong, I couldn't do it with 3 pairs, as I need the cartesian product of all of the inputs, so in this case 3X3, nXm, nXmXj, etc
The PARTITION BY clause seems to be a good direction, however I couldn't figure out, how tell that PARTITION BY xlimit.val < ???what_comes_here and zlimit.val > ???what_comes_here???

Comment: I think you're going to find the issue is performing the SUM too early, before you had the cartesian product of pairs joined with your data.  The SUM probably needed to be done grouped by xlimit.val, zlimit.val.  That's assuming you didn't want the running sums too, which I don't think you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

```
--------------
WITH xmlimit (val) AS (
        select * from (values (3), (5), (10)) AS x
     )
   , zmlimit (val) AS (
        select * from (values (100), (500), (800)) AS x
     )
select SUM(y)
     , xmlimit.val xmlimit
     , zmlimit.val zmlimit
  from testtable AS cumsum
  JOIN xmlimit
    ON cumsum.x < xmlimit.val
  JOIN zmlimit
    ON cumsum.z > zmlimit.val
 GROUP BY xmlimit.val, zmlimit.val
--------------

+--------+---------+---------+
| SUM(y) | xmlimit | zmlimit |
+--------+---------+---------+
|    210 |       3 |     100 |
|    610 |       5 |     100 |
|   1680 |      10 |     100 |
|    960 |      10 |     500 |
|    100 |      10 |     800 |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

I adjusted your SQL to work with an engine I'm using.
If you like this result, just remove your running SUM window function and directly perform your SUM in the context of GROUP BY x, z;  If your SQL is valid, adjust it like this (roughly):

```
select 
    SUM(cumsum.y),
    xlimit.val,
    zlimit.val
from sampletable as cumsum
        join (select * from values (3), (5), (10)) as xlimit(val)
            on cumsum.x < xlimit.val
        join (select * from values (100), (200), (800)) as zlimit(val)
            on cumsum.z > zlimit.val
    group by xlimit.val, zlimit.val;
```